# Update subscription windows azure after free trial

Tags: azure, subscription

at the moment I am using a free trial account for windows azure.

The question is if when the trial period expires, can I update the account to a 'normal' one and set a spending monthly limit? because this website (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jimoneil/archive/2011/12/28/windows-azure-trial-account-spending-limit.aspx) says 'no'. The info is a little bit old and the free trial conditions changed, so I am not 100% sure.

(Spending monthly limit doesn't mean that I always will pay the same, isn't it? but I will pay max. what I choose and when the price is reached then the services stopped...?

I don't know if the default pricing is set to pay-as-you-go.

Thanks.

Comment: What does Microsoft say? It is always better to show evidence of having tried to answer your question yourself first; if nothing else, it avoids us duplicating your work or pointing you toward things you have already tried. Please [edit] your question to include any additional information; do not reply in comments.

Comment: What website says "no" what did the information say exactly ( provide a link ) and have you contacted Microsoft and ask for assistance in upgrading your account from a trial to a paid account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here is a link to the Azure Billing FAQ](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/13626.azure-accounts-and-billing-faq.aspx)

In this link it states that all trials will rollover into subscriptions automatically unless you specify otherwise.

The default account type is set to pay as you go with whatever spending limit you hav chosen.

Lastly - if you go over your spending or allocation limits, the service gets disabled until you either up your limit or pay your bill.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, it is more or less the same info I read in the link I wrote. And they talk about free trials conditions that are old.
I will send an email direct to billing support.

Comment: I dont see how this information is that out of date.. it was updates less than 3 weeks ago.

Comment: Well, they talk about a free trial 90 days with some limitations, when actually it is 150€/200$ credit for 1month. I was just wondering if when they modified the free trial offer, others conditions also changed.

Comment: good ol' microsoft..

Comment: This answer is no longer correct as of 2016. They now "pause" your website until you confirm you would like to use pay as you go. I found this out as my website became uncontactable after exactly 30 days.